# Who were the 'Water People of North America' and what do we know about them?

Tags: native-americans, north-america

I stumbled upon a [website showing fascinating water structures](https://landbeforetime.home.blog/2019/03/29/the-water-people-of-north-america/) in North America. Unfortunately it does not say much about the culture which built these and only speculates about the potential usages of these structures. Given that they appear to be very large, I think this must have been researched by someone. Many of them look like irrigation channels, but some are really mind-boggling, a few examples below.

**What do we know about the people and purposes behind these fascinating structures?**

108°28′35.5″W, 50°34′17.1″N
[image]

location unknown
[image]

Comment: The first picture is Boggy Lake (in Saskatchewan province) which is 5km south of Cabri. The website for Cabri notes the following; "Boggy Lake, a man-made ‘duck hotel’ that provides a natural nesting and staging area for water fowl." So man-made but probably relatively modern.